# Average yearly increase

Tags: statistics

I have a table with years (in 10 year steps) and the corresponding population. The average 10-year increase (in %) is easy to calculate. I just calculated the increase between every 10 year gap and used the geometric mean.

How could I calculate the average yearly increase from this information?

Another question: How should I calculate if I wanted to know how big the population is in a particular year in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average yearly increase is the tenth root of the average 10 year increase, so if your population doubles in ten years (a multiplier of 2) the multiplier for each year is $2^{1/10} \approx 1.072$  To forecast the population some years in the future, take your current population and multiply it by the multplier once for each year.  So if our multiplier is $1.072$ and we want the population in $5$ years, the population will multiply by $1.072^5 \approx 1.416$

Comment: I have a 10 year avarage increase of 3,6% (which means multiplier of 0,036). The tenth root would give me 0,72 which would translate to 72 % increase. This sound a bit too heigh of an increase since the ten year average increase is so low.

Comment: The ten year multiplier is then $1.036.$  The tenth root is about $1.003543$

Comment: Yes right. My mistake. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have another question. For calculating the 10-year average increase I took the increase between all 10 year gaps through (current value-old value)/old value and then I just put it into the geometric mean formula. Is this correct?

Comment: The increase is just new/old and you can take the geometric mean of those. Another way is just take the final value/starting value to get the overall increase, then take the 1/total years power to get the annual increase.